# Getting the return value from Bootstrap.php in a Zend Framework application

Tags: php, zend-framework

I was wondering how (if possible) would you access the return value of an _init method in the Bootstrap.php file of a Zend Framework app?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every return value of _init method in a Bootstrap.php is being threated as a resource, and consequently saved in a bootstrap's Zend_Registry container. Thus you can do e.g.:

```
 // in Bootstrap.php
 protected function _initTest() {
     return 'some return value';
 }
```

And in some action in a controller:

```
 $theTestResource = $this->getInvokeArg('bootstrap')->getResource('test');

 // OR you can also do the same as

 $theTestResource = $this->getInvokeArg('bootstrap')->getContainer()->test;
```

Comment: +1 for the `getContainer()->test` variant. I didn't know that one. Man, Marcin, you are on an SO reputation stampede. ;-)

Comment: Can also be done  Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getParam('bootstrap')->getResource('test');

Comment: @David Weinraub. Thanks David. For a couple last weeks I had plenty of free time, and I spent some of this time at SO:-)